# Simple Leaky Bucket Async and Low Footprint

Tags: c#, performance, algorithm

I'm working on a simple [Leaky Bucket algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_bucket).
I have found a lot of samples on the internet, but something always bothers me.
Most of them use Collections and DateTime to track current actions and calculate the time of a Delay.

So, I try a controversial (according to my co-workers) implementation, using 2 semaphores and a separate thread to do the leaky job.

That's in production now, handling thousands of requests per second without a hitch.

The logic was based on the code found in [this](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2019/11/24/implementing-a-leaky-bucket-client-in-net-core/) article.

I have 3 questions:

1. Is it a problem to use a semaphore inside another?
2. Do you guys see any problem with this code or this approach?
3. Can we optimize something to gain better performance?

**SimpleLeakyBucket.cs**

```
namespace Limiter
{
    using System;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    public class SimpleLeakyBucket : IDisposable
    {
        readonly SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
        readonly SemaphoreSlim semaphoreMaxFill = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
        readonly CancellationTokenSource leakToken = new CancellationTokenSource();

        readonly Config configuration;
        readonly Task leakTask;
        int currentItems = 0;

        public SimpleLeakyBucket(Config configuration)
        {
            this.configuration = configuration;
            leakTask = Task.Run(Leak, leakToken.Token); //start leak task here
        }

        public async Task Wait(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            await semaphore.WaitAsync(cancellationToken);

            try
            {
                if (currentItems >= configuration.MaxFill)
                {
                    await semaphoreMaxFill.WaitAsync(cancellationToken);
                }

                Interlocked.Increment(ref currentItems);

                return;
            }
            finally
            {
                semaphore.Release();
            }
        }


        void Leak()
        {
            //Wait for our first queue item. 
            while (currentItems == 0 && !leakToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }

            while (!leakToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(configuration.LeakRateTimeSpan);

                if (currentItems > 0)
                {
                    var leak = Math.Min(currentItems, configuration.LeakRate);
                    Interlocked.Add(ref currentItems, -leak);

                    if (semaphoreMaxFill.CurrentCount == 0)
                    {
                        semaphoreMaxFill.Release();
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (!leakToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                leakToken.Cancel();
                leakTask.Wait();
            }

            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }


        public class Config
        {
            public int MaxFill { get; set; }
            public TimeSpan LeakRateTimeSpan { get; set; }
            public byte LeakRate { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage sample**

```
namespace LimiterPlayground
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //will limite the execution by 100 per 10 second
            using var leaky = new SimpleLeakyBucket(new SimpleLeakyBucket.Config
            {
                LeakRate = 100,
                LeakRateTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),
                MaxFill = 100
            });

            Task.WaitAll(Enumerable.Range(1, 100000).Select(async idx =>
            {
                await leaky.Wait(CancellationToken.None);
                Console.WriteLine($"[{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss.fff}] - {idx.ToString().PadLeft(5, '0')}");
            }).ToArray());

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is .NET version?

Comment: The code is compatible and run on netcorepp3.1 and net5.0.
But i´m think thid is compatible with net48 too.

Comment: From a bird-view the code isn't completely thread-safe. I'll dig in it a bit later. Just interesting: would there a difference in behavior between 100 items per 10 sec and 10 items per 1 sec?

Comment: @FabioAvila Am I right that your implementation is based on [this](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2019/11/24/implementing-a-leaky-bucket-client-in-net-core/)?

Comment: @aepot - tnks for your time. About your question, there is a difference if you have a lot of tasks to run.
In 100 itens per 10sec for example:  you are can queue up to 100 tasks at same time
In 10 itens per 1sec, you can queur only 10 taks at max.
if your taks are fast, there is a big difference.

Comment: @PeterCsala, youre right this is one of the code base that i bases of. Sorry for dont put this in question, becouse i get too much samples on the internet to do my test i forgot the credits, my bad. I´ll update the question for this.

Comment: Iam working on a variation ot this code, that not use Interlocked, this user direct the properties ans recources of the semaphoreMaxFill property.